# Hahn banach theorem and distance

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$.For every $x \in X$ we define the set $P_Y(x)=\{y_0 \in Y:||y_0-x||=\inf_{y \in Y}||x-y||\}$.
>   If $x \in X$ \ $Y$ and $y_0\in Y$ then prove that $y_0 \in P_Y(x)$ iff exists $f \in A=\{f \in X^*|f(y)=0 ,\forall y \in Y\}$ such that $f(x-y_0)=||x-y_0||$ and $||f||=1$.

I came up with a solution for this exercise but i don't if it is completely correct at all.

Here is my atempt:

Let $d=\inf_{y \in Y}||x-y||$ and $y_0 \in Y$ and $x \in X$ \ $Y$.

We define $Z=\{y+tx|t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $g:Z \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(tx+y)=t||x-y_0||$.

We have that $g(y)=0,\forall y \in Y$ and $g(x-y_0)=||x-y_0||$ and $g$ is a linear functional.

Also $|g(tx+y)|=|t|||x-y_0||=|t|\inf_{y \in Y}||x-y||\leqslant|t|||\frac{y}{t}+x||=||tx+y||$ thus $||g|| \leqslant 1$ and $g \in Z^*$.

Also $||g||=\sup_{z \neq 0,z \in Z} \frac{|g(z)|}{||z||}$ and $||x-y_0|| \neq0$ because if $||x-y_0||=0$ then $\inf_{y \in Y}||x-y||=0$ thus $x \in Y$ (because of the fact that $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$).

Now we take $z=x-y_0$ and we have that $||g|| \geqslant \frac{|g(x-y_0)|}{||x-y_0||}=1$ thus $||g||=1$

From one of the applications of Hahn-Banach theorem we derive that $\exists f \in X^*$ such that $||f||=||g||=1$ and $f(x-y_0)=||x-y_0||$

Conversely suppose that exist a bounded linear functional with the properties mentioned above.

We already have that $\inf_{y \in Y}||x-y|| \leqslant ||x-y_0||$

Also $||x-y_0||=|f(x-y_0)| \leqslant \max\{|f(x)|:f \in A ,||f|| \leqslant 1\}=\inf_{y \in Y}||x-y||$(this is another application of Hahn-Banach theorem).

Thus $\inf_{y \in Y}||x-y||=||x-y_0|| \Longrightarrow y_0 \in P_Y(x)$

Is this proof completely correct?

Thank you in advance!